# Fire fake enter keypress in Javascript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

I would like to fake an 'enter' keypress event in the browser, without the help of jQuery.

Here's what I tried :

```
var keyEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
keyEvent.initKeyboardEvent('keyup', true, false, null, 0, false, 0, false, 13, 0);
elem.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
```

where elem is one particular element (found with `document.querySelector()`)

However the Javascript console tells me `initKeyboardEvent()` is not a function.

Now, the documentation does say [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyboardEvent) that this function is deprecated, but doesn't redirect to the right way to do it nowadays, and I couldn't find any example of how to achieve this by myself either.

Any help on that one?

Comment: @Juhana The post you're referring to has an answer using `initKeyEvent()` which is **also** deprecated (just like `initKeyboardEvent()`. MDN documentation says: "Do not use this method any more, use the KeyboardEvent() constructor instead."

Comment: @NicolasM The redirect you're looking for goes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent

Comment: The duplicate also has an answer using `KeyboardEvent`.

Comment: It is a duplicate, indeed ! Sorry for not noticing ! The answer with `KeyboardEvent` is the one i used, it gets straight to the point. Thanks !